# Get querystring from URLReferrer

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, query-string, http-referer, request.querystring

I am trying to get the QueryString value like this `Request.QueryString("SYSTEM")` from a UrlReferrer. I see i can use this `Request.UrlReferrer.Query()` but it doesn't allow me to specify the exact parameter

I could parse the Query() value, but I want to know if it is possible to do something like this `Request.UrlReferrer.QueryString("SYSTEM")`

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You could do

```
HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.UrlReferrer.Query)["SYSTEM"]
```

That is c# in vb is is probably something like

```
HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.UrlReferrer.Query())("SYSTEM")
```

Answer (score 1):

In VB.NET, one way to get the value of "SYSTEM" from the UrlReferrer is:

```
HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.UrlReferrer.Query).GetValues("SYSTEM")(0)
```